# Setting width / height after using setRotation

Tags: android, resize, android-relativelayout, dimensions

I'm building an Android app which will be used on Mini PC's / Cyclone devices powered by Android and one requirement I have is to force the app to switch into portrait orientation.  My first thought was to set the orientation programmatically like so:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Which works on tablets / phones but not on Mini / Cyclone PC's - the orientation remains landscape.  My next thought was to use the setRotation() method of the RelativeLayout  (which is my root container) to rotate it 90 degrees - that works great but the width / height doesn't adapt itself to the size of the screen.  What I end up with is the RelativeLayout rotated by 90 degrees but the width and height are still in landscape.  I tried manually setting the width / height of the RelativeLayout control by setting it's LayoutParams and although that sorted out the width, the height is incorrect as it only takes up half the screen.  This is what I'm currently doing:

```
m_container.setRotation(-90);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams portraitParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(Util.getDisplayHeight(MainActivity.this), Util.getDisplayWidth(MainActivity.this));

m_container.setLayoutParams(portraitParams);
```

The getDisplayHeight/Width methods correctly returns the width / height of the screen.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong / have any suggestions how to get the width / height set correctly of my RelativeLayout m_container?

Many thanks,

Tony

Comment: Did you ever get a resolution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting android:screenOrientation="portrait" in the AndroidManifest.xml on the relevant activities ?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Yes I've tried setting the screenOrientation property in the manifest file too, but unfortunately it didn't work.  It's worth noting that it does work on tablets / handheld devices which have an accelerometer, but my app is being run on a Mini-PC which doesn't have an accelerometer - which I'm guessing is part of the problem.